# How can I solve this improper integral?

Tags: calculus

I have problems solving this integral:

$\int_1^\infty {1\over(a^2+x^2)^{3/2}}dx$

Mi result was 
$\int_1^\infty {1\over(a^2+x^2)^{3/2}}dx={{\sqrt{1+a^2}}-1\over a^2\sqrt{1+a^2}}$

but i don´t know if that is right.

Comment: excuse me, te expresion must be $(a^2+x^2)$ inteasted of (a^2-x2)

Comment: It appears to be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct!

Simply substitute $x=a \tan y$ so that $dx=a \sec^2 y dy$.

Then we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}&=\int_{\arctan(1/a)}^{\pi/2}\frac{a\sec^2y }{|a|^3\sec^3y}\,dy\\\\
&=\left.\left( \frac{1}{a^2}\sin y\,\right)\right|_{\arctan(1/a)}^{\pi/2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(1-(1+a^2)^{-1/2}\right)
\end{align}$$